# Round up to two places of decimal of java without reassigning to new variable

Tags: java, decimal

I have the following code where I need to print value up to two decimal places removing the dot(.) from the number. 
How ever sometimes it print up to two and sometimes up to three places off decimal.

```
public class CheckSubString3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Double[] d={134344.00d,234434.08d,234434.02d};
        for(int i=0; i<d.length; i++){
            System.out.println((d[i])*(25)/100);
            System.out.println(parseLonggetFormattedAmount((d[i])*(25)/100));
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    private static String parseLonggetFormattedAmount(double d) {
        DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat
                .getInstance(new Locale("en", "gb"));
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        FieldPosition f = new FieldPosition(0);
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
        String value = format.format(d, s, f).toString().replace(',', ' ')
                .replace('.', ' ');
        return value.replaceAll(" ","");
    }
}
```

Below is the output:

```
original value 33586.0
required value 3358600

original value 58608.52
required value 5860852

original value 58608.505
required value 58608505// This line is giving upto 3 places of decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [NumberFormat documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), you could use `setMaximumFractionDigits(int newValue)`

> Sets the maximum number of digits allowed in the fraction portion of a number.

just put it in your function `parseLonggetFormattedAmount(double d)`:

```
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Comment: sounds nice. but again it should round to nearest two places of decimal

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply want to multiply the doubles by 100 and round to the nearest integer. So your method could be written:

```
private static String parseLonggetFormattedAmount(double d) {
  return String.valueOf(Math.round(d * 100));
}
```

Which outputs:

> 3358600
>   5860852
>   5860851